# Emacs / C-x 3 / Slightly Wider Vertical Bar

Tags: emacs

I'm in Emacs. I have a window setup with C-x 3 (so there is a vertical bar that splits the two buffers.)

Right now, what splits the two buffers is a single "|" char.

What I would prefer for my vertical split is something that looks like "  |  " -- i.e. I want a buffer of 2 spaces on either side of the vertical bar.

Is there an easy way to construct this?

Thanks!

Comment: Slime-repl isn't relevant, this is a standard emacs construct. Please edit your question to remove slimey things. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this basically does the trick, although you'll get the margin at the far left and right sides of the frame as well; so it's not strictly for the window separator.

```el
(setq-default left-margin-width 2)         
(setq-default right-margin-width 2)
```

The part I'm not sure of is the effect it has on the minibuffer.

I tried `setq`ing those buffer-local values to `nil` in `minibuffer-setup-hook`, but that didn't resolve it.

Comment: I like this. Is there any way to change the '|' character to a full colored vertical box? [The dash is still slightly distracting.]